# Query the Postgres DB table data from HTML webpage using PHP

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have a postgres database table with 6 columns

```
  report_dt      | configured_capacity_tb | present_capacity_tb | dfs_remaining_tb | dfs_used_tb | env
```

The 5th column should appear as a drop down in HTML webpage when i select an option from that drop down and hit submit I should get the data(from postgres db table) in a form of table on webpage

Any help greatly appreciated following is my broken code

```
 echo 'Connection attempt succeeded.';
 } else {
 echo 'Connection attempt failed.';
 }
$sql =<<<EOF
select * from cluster_report_tab;
EOF;
$ret = pg_query($db, $sql);
   if(!$ret){
      echo pg_last_error($db);
      exit;
}
<<<I AM STUCK AT THIS PIECE>>>>

<html>
<head><title>Cluster Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<table width="600" cellpadding= "10" cellspacing="1" border="2">
<tr align="center" valign="top">
<td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1" bgcolor="#64b1ff">
<h3>Hadoop Cluster Report</h3>
****DROP DOWN SHOULD COME HERE*****
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</td></tr></table></form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I select the option from that drop down and hit submit button on webpage It should display me the query result# select * from cluster_report_tab where env='DHEP'; on the webpage.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you fetch the results from pg_query?

Comment: That was my biggest problem, I couldn't write a code to fetch the query result as i wanted. I want the result in the form of table but I am having hard time doing that...I used $_POST but didn't help much...

Comment: What went wrong when you used pg_fetch_array() or one of the other functions? Without code and error messages, we have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry...Okay the following is my script
        while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
        $ReportDate = $row[0];
        $ConfiguredCapacity = $row[1];
        $PresentCapacity = $row[2];
        $Remaining = $row[3];
        $Used = $row[4];
        $Env = $row[5];
I wanna use this variables to produce the table...If i have 100 rows in the database table I need to display 100 rows with a table on html webpage...I never got what i want so I did not share this..I did not see errors but I am not achieving what I want...

Comment: $result doesn't exist in your other code, there you use $ret.

Comment: @ManikumarJuttukonda: Please edit your post to add new details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind...The following piece of code solved my problem...Thanks for all your suggestions

```
$result=pg_query("select * from cluster_report_tab where env = '$_POST[Envi]'");
                 while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
                 echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[5]</td>";
                 echo "</tr>";
                 }
                 pg_close($db);
                 ?>
```