# Postgres db to html via js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, postgresql

So our DB guy set up the the data base in postgresql on heroku.

I found a great article for the js:
[Query the Postgres DB table data from HTML webpage using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538643/query-the-postgres-db-table-data-from-html-webpage-using-php)

he defines the method for the query but not the HTML tie in.

I am not using php nor nodejs, but basic HTML5.  In these version I do not plan to use local storage.

Could you please help me bridge the gap?

I am open to any additions and ideas

Here is what I have:

```
$result=pg_query("select * from [table-name] where env = 
'$_POST[Envi]'");
  while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<img src='$row[5]'/>";
    echo "<p>'$row[8]'</p>";
    echo "<p>'$row[9]' + ', '$row[10]' + '  ' + '$row[11]</p>";
    pg_close($db)
   }
```

[table-name] is a place holder ;)

Do I need template file?

Comment: "I am not using PHP" - The code you posted looks _a lot_ like PHP.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to install Node.js to accomplish this.  You can then create a REST API that can be consumed in your browser.

Comment: I mean, you've got a heroku app, right? What language does it target?

Comment: Did you ever hear about SQL injection? Never ever allow user input in a piece of SQL without proper security.